# How can I get a list of the count of finished products and corresponding correction values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with products being finished and corrections that have occurred on the machines. I would like to get a list of the amount of products that get done and the corresponding correction that had to happen.

in this example i want only the products of type A that have 'finished' and the corisponding 'CORR' value.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
data = {
    'STATE': ['started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished' ,'started'  ,'finished'],
    'LENS':  ['Product A','Product A','Product B','Product B','Product A','Product A','Product A','Product A','Product B','Product B','Product A','Product A','Product A','Product A','Product A','Product A'],
    'CORR': [0.1         ,      None ,    None   ,   None    ,   None    ,   None    ,0.2        ,    None   ,    None   ,   None    ,      None ,    None   ,     None  ,     None  ,   0.15    ,None]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

what i hope to get is the following i present it here as two lists, but one 2d array might be nicer.

```
CORR: [0.1,0.2,0.15]
count:[2,3,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this sorts the order to be ascending for "CORR".  I have assumed that "CORR" is forward-filled, as this makes the counts add correctly.

```py
# comments for each line:
# 1. groupby forward-filled "CORR", "LENS" (for products), and "STATE" (else duplicates)
# 2. count in the "LENS" column, as contains all data, whilst "CORR" has np.nan
# 3. unstack LENS and STATE to columns
# 4. get "Product A" and "finished" (as only need 1 column)
# 5. reset index and convert to numpy array
df.groupby([df.CORR.ffill(), "LENS", "STATE"])\
    ["LENS"].count()\
        .unstack([1,2])\
            .loc[:, ("Product A", "finished")]\
                .reset_index().to_numpy().T
#Out[]:
#array([[0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 ],
#       [2.  , 1.  , 3.  ]])
```

Comment: could you help me a bit more maybe, I cant seem to figure out how to keep the original index of the values in the "CORR" column.  Meaning i want the data to be like: 
[[0   0.1    2.  ]
 [14  0.15  1.  ]
 [7   0.2     3.  ]]

could you please help me?

Comment: You could do change the code to do the following: `df.reset_index().groupby([df.CORR.ffill(), "LENS", "STATE"])\
    .agg({"LENS": "count", "index": "min"})\
        .xs(("Product A", "finished"), axis=0, level=[1, 2])\
            .reset_index().to_numpy().T[np.ix_([2,0,1])]`

Comment: Or you could append to the array the following code (there are probably many other alternatives too): `df.CORR.ffill().loc[(df.STATE == "finished") & (df.LENS == "Product A")].drop_duplicates().index`